# Difference between numeric and string value in PHP

Tags: php, string, numeric

I am getting a difference when comparing two string which are `0` and `'0'` in PHP. Can I do anything to make them be compared equally in an if action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you compare using:

```
if ('0' == 0) // if '0' is equal to 0
```

it should return true as the values are compared with the string being converted to a number.  If you do:

```
if ('0' === 0) // if '0' is identical to 0
```

it will return false as they have to be of the same type too.

Note the triple '='

Answer (score 1):

You can also force their type to be the same before comparing:

```
if((int)'0' === (int)0) {
    // true
}
if((string)'0' === (string)0) {
    // true
}
```