# Simple comparison in PHP if($var == 0) not working?

Tags: php

I'm getting data from a MySQL database and trying to check if the column has data in it or not. Here's what one of the array elements looks like:

```
[2] => Array 
(   
        [p_name] => This is text
)
```

Now I have the following statement:

```
if($products[2]['p_name'] == 0)
      echo '$products[2][\'p_name\'] == 0';
```

The output is:

```
"$products[2]['p_name'] == 0"
```

Now, is it just me, or is that not make any sense whatsoever?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804553/difference-between-numeric-and-string-value-in-php

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6843030/53114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A textual string casted to a number is always 0: `(int) 'This is Text'` is equal to 0.

You could just use the `empty()` function or `is_numeric()` and then your code:

```
if (empty($var))
```

(which check if `$var` is either `""` (an empty string), `0` (0 as an integer), `0.0` (0 as a float), `"0"` (0 as a string), `NULL`, `FALSE` or `array()`).

or

```
if (is_numeric($var) && $var === 0))
```

Comment: Thanks! So how do I check if the cell is empty?

Comment: If it's always a string, use `=== ''`. Otherwise use `empty()`. Have a read about [type comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're comparing text to number. This will always compare 0 to 0

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to why `"This is text" == 0`, it's because PHP is loosely typed, and when you compare the string with an integer, the string is casted to `0`.

This is likely not the desired behaviour, so you will need to use the equality operator, for example,

```
`"This is text" == 0` // True
`"This is text" === 0` // False
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dLS8Cn)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($products[2]['p_name']) && !empty($products[2]['p_name']) ) 
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: `isset()` is useless here.  No one should use this code-only answer.